# How to define a list in Terraform that may be empty depending on a variable?

Tags: terraform

I need to define a resource in Terraform (v0.10.8) that has a list property that may or may not be empty depending on a variable, see `volume_ids` in the following definition:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "worker_node" {
  count = "${var.droplet_count}"
  [...]
  volume_ids = [
    "${var.volume_size != 0 ? element(digitalocean_volume.worker.*.id, count.index) : ""}"
  ]
}

resource "digitalocean_volume" "worker" {
  count = "${var.volume_size != 0 ? var.droplet_count : 0}"
  [...]
}
```

}

The solution I've come up with fails however in the case where the list should be empty (i.e., `var.volume_size` is 0):

```
volume_ids = [
  "${var.volume_size != 0 ? element(digitalocean_volume.worker.*.id, count.index) : ""}"
]
```

The following Terraform error message is produced:

```
* module.workers.digitalocean_droplet.worker_node[1]: element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${var.volume_size != 0 ? element(digitalocean_volume.worker.*.id, count.index) : ""}
```

How should I correctly write my definition of `volume_ids`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of many language shortcomings in terraform. The hacky workaround is to tack an empty list onto your empty list.

```
${var.volume_size != 0 ? element(concat(digitalocean_volume.worker.*.id , list("")), count.index) : ""}
```

Comment: I found out about this in the meantime too, thanks. I think you can remove the boolean condition though? `element` will wrap around the index if it surpasses the list's length, so just looking up `list("")` should work in case there are no volumes .

Comment: The truth, of course, is that Terraform is not a language, it is a config file format. What we need are tools that wrap Terraform, like stack_master/stacker/etc. for CloudFormation, which let you code in proper programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Since this answer was written, several new constructs make this problem just a little less gross.  As of terraform 1.x syntax can be changed from:

```
element(concat(digitalocean_volume.worker.*.id , list(""))
```

```
coalescelist(digitalocean_volume.worker[*].id, [""])
```