# Terraform split/join/list

Tags: terraform

I recently found the following line of terraform in our code (some values sanitized):

```
subnet_ids = [ "${split(",", var.xxx_lb ? join(",", data.yyy_ids.private.ids) : join(",", concat(data.yyy_ids.public.ids, list(""))))}" ]
```

I'm trying to understand why code would be written this way. More specifically, what is the final join doing? Pulling it out for clarity:

```
join(",", concat(data.yyy_ids.public.ids, list("")))
```

It seems that someone (no longer at the company) was trying to ensure that a non-empty list is returned. We definitely don't want the empty ("") item in the list.

So, the questions here are:

1. What logically is going on in this statement?
2. Is there a better way?
3. If there is not a better way, how can we remove the empty entry from
   the resulting list?

Update for others who may run into this sort of code:

Terraform versions lower than 0.12 conditionals don't work with lists, so join/split is used to turn lists into strings and then back to lists:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12453

Comment: They were using a ternary operator to make sure if the `var.xxx_lb` is `true` then the first `join()` is applied and if the `var.xxx_lb` is `false` the second `join` is performed. Also, the first part of the expression is related to private subnet IDs while the second one is related to public subnet IDs. Maybe if the (A)LB is public/private then a different `join` is used. The `list()` is deprecated but it seems someone was doing exactly what you said.

Comment: Also, it would be good to know which provider/resource this is in order to shed more light on the question you have.

Comment: I happened across a related item: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415781/284598

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What logically is going on in this statement?

The original author attempts to create a list with the **subnet ids**

`a)` The first split statement will take a string in this case the subnet ids and return them as a list, by splitting them based on the delimiter `,`

---

```
var.xxx_lb ? clause_if_true : clause_if_false
```

`b)` Next terraform will evaluate this variable as a boolean and according to the result you will get the public or the private subnet ids, by employing the ternary operator syntax

---

```
join(",", data.yyy_ids.private.ids)
```

`c)` In case the boolean value is true, terraform will examine this part

This will return a string by joining the items of the list.
And add the delimeter `,`. I assume the reason that he attempts to join them as a string is to be accordance with the section `a)`

---

```
join(",", concat(data.yyy_ids.public.ids, list("")))
```

`d)` If the boolean value in `b)` evaluates to false terraform will examine this part.
The concat function takes as input lists and returns them as a `single` list.

And then performs the same logic as in `c)`

The `list` function is deprecated, `tolist` should be used instead.

> Is there a better way?

I would employ a straight forward way. Check the boolean value, if it is true get the list with private ids. If false the public ones.

```
subnet_ids =  var.xxx_lb ? data.yyy_ids.private.ids : data.yyy_ids.public.ids
```

Comment: Fantastic detail! The main thing that I'm curious about is why the list("") exists at all. It is making our tf plan output have empty entries that don't really cause changes.

Comment: In my understanding it is not needed, maybe at the time of writing, had to do with specific versions? The developer making tests?

Comment: FWIW, we're still on TF v0.11. :-(

Comment: I found the reason why the split/join was used: in terraform < v0.12 conditionals don't work with lists. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12453